# Get source from a <tr> element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the source of a tr element using JQuery.

For this I'm using the selector below :

```
$('#mygrid > table tr')
```

On console I can see this selector returns me this :

```
<tr class="red-background">
<td class="date">10/07/2018</td>
<td class="hora">13:09</td>
</tr>
```

The return is actually an object, not a string :

```
typeof $('#grid-historicos > table tr')
"object"
```

[image]

So I can't use the method `.html()`

So what is the right way to get the HTML source of the  element? I need only this part as a string :

```
<tr class="red-background">
```

Comment: is a object because you have more than one $('#mygrid > table tr') right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/632Lc01v/1/)**.

You need to select the `tr` line you want to target using the index `[0]` in my example, then select the `outerHTML` and split the result then finally get the first line  :

```js
console.log($('#mygrid > table tr')[0].outerHTML.split('\n')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mygrid">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr class="red-background">
      <td class="date">10/07/2018</td>
      <td class="hora">13:09</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```